# How can I take input and make a list with it on Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

I'm doing homework for Basic Artificial Intelligence, and the problem is, "Make a Prolog program that can read 2 lists of numeric values and 
concatenate them", so I'm a total noob and I have no idea how to take a input from Prolog and put it on a list one by one

```
%I have only make the while func so that you  
%put the total numbers you want on the list
p_while(0) :- !.
p_while(N) :- 
   N > 0,
   N1 is N - 1,
   read(Num),
   p_while(N1).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard predicate called `append/3`. You can use it to read two lists of numerical values from the prompt and concatenate them, like this:

```
?- append([1,2], [3,4], L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4].
```

You can use `listing/1` to see how `append/3` is defined:

```
?- listing(append/3).
lists:append([], L, L).
lists:append([H|T], L, [H|R]) :-
    append(T, L, R).

true.
```